# Get a list of subsites and users access rights from a sharepoint 2013 site collection using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

I need to access a list of subsites of a sharepoint 2013 site collection and get a list of users access rights as well using powershell. So far I can only access only site collections but not the subsites within it. When trying to use any command starting with "SP", I get an error